# Order of the agents in agentset don't match

Tags: netlogo, agentset

I have a doubt and apologize if the answer is very obvious. I created the following code. Pretty simple & straightforward:

```
patches-own [ tl ls ls2 ls3 ls4 tsl]
turtles-own [mysize]

to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks
  crt 5
  ask turtles [ set heading random 360 jump random 20 set mysize random-float 1]
  asd
  inspect patch 0 0
end

to asd
  let old sum [mysize] of turtles
  ask patches [ set tl other turtles
    set tsl [self] of tl
    set ls [distance myself] of tl 
    set ls2 [distance myself ^ 2] of tl
    set ls3 [(mysize) / old] of tl
    ]
  ;print tl

end

to initial
  set heading random 360 jump random 20 set mysize 1
end

to go
  inspect patch 0 0
  ask turtles [ fd 1 set mysize mysize + random-float 1]
  let qwe random-float 1
  print qwe
  if qwe < 0.2 and count turtles > 2 [ask one-of turtles [die]]
  if qwe > 0.8 [ ask one-of patches [sprout 1 [initial]]]
  asd
  tick
end
```

As you can see, i have a inspect function in the code and below is the snapshot:

[image]
My question is why is the `ls` and `ls2` agents out of order. Agentset `TSL` shows the order of the turtles, so shouldn't the other agentsets created based on that follow the same order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you sort them somehow, Netlogo will query agents in an agentset in a random order. Functionally, `ask tl` follows the same logic as `ask turtles`, and the same goes for retrieving variables from an agentset. For example, if you use the command center to try the code below several times (after running your `setup` and `asd`), you will note that the order of agents queried is not the same every time.

`ask patch 0 0 [ print [distance myself] of tl ]`

All this to say that the creation of a patch's "tsl" list is independent of the creation of your other lists. It is not an ordered list, it is a list of randomly called turtles from the agentset "tl". One way to get consistent ordering of an agentset is to use one of the `sort` primitives.

Comment: So in that case if i do some operation like find the turtle with minimum value in one of the agentsets, using `min-one-of` will it matter that all the agentsets are not similarly ordered or will Netlogo give me the correct result?

Comment: It should return the correct result so long as you are querying an agentset- something like `ask patch 0 0 [ ask min-one-of tl [distance myself ]  [ set size 3 ] ]`. Also note that in your example screenshot only "tl" is an agentset, the rest are lists- you query a list of agents differently than you do an agentset.

Comment: Since you are saying that only `tl is an agentset` and everything else is a list. If i want to find the turtle with the `min` value in one of the lists say `ls` I cannot use `lput` right? I may be able to get the index or the `position` of the minimum value in the list but when i reference the position to identify the turtle in the agentset it will throw an error. For example `set tl other turtles
set ls [distance myself ^ 2] of tl
set index position (min ls) ls`. Till this point it would work but when i use `lput item index tl`. I would get an error asking for a list instead of agentset

Comment: I may not be understanding you correctly, but I think you could skip a step and just use `sort-on` to build, for each patch, an ordered list of turtles sorted for whatever reporter you want. For example, if you wanted a list of turtles based on distance from the patch, you could use `ask patches [ set ls sort-on [ distance myself ] turtles ]`. This will create a list of turtles in ascending order of distance from the patch. To get the first turtle, have that patch ask the `first` in the list to do a thing- eg `ask patch 0 0 [ ask first ls [ set color red ] ]`

Comment: What i meant was if I want to find  which turtle is the closest to a patch as you have mentioned in your last comment. If say the first turtle in the list ls is `turtle 7` then I want the output to be `(turtle 7)`. I dont want the value itself but the turtle with the lowest or greatest value in the list. Since the initial reference `tl` is an agentset and remaining are lists it would thrown an error when using `lput` to find the turtle

Comment: Right. `Lput` is regardless not what you want, it just appends to a list. Instead, just take what I said in the last comment and modify it so that the patch outputs the first item in the list- eg `ask patch 0 0 [ print first ls ]` (After you have made "ls" a sorted list as in my previous comment )

Comment: Got it..Thanks a ton. Appreciate the help and you taking time to patiently answer all my questions.

Comment: Happy to help! Cheers.